# Want to clean string before using it in database

Tags: php

I want to clean user input before using it in database. 
I'm using `mysql_real_escape-string` but it seems in some low versions of php its not working. 
I want to use stripshlases. Will it work for me ?
What should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and mysql will take care of any database-specific escaping necessary. Beyond that, though, is a business logic problem.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_real_escape_string has been deprecated for some time now.  PHP.net has a [page to help you find a replacement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

stripslashes will not prevent SQL injection, and will also cause problems with potentially legitimate user input.